# Access the main timeline in a swc

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have some animation that was created in the main timeline in an FLA

I want to publish this as a SWC for importing via Flash Builder.

However- I can't find a way to do this. Any ideas?

The only workaround I know of so far is to copy all the frames into a movieclip symbol and then set that to "export for actionscript" This isn't ideal since then I need to reposition the entire animation so it's at 0,0- and since there are objects moving outside the bounds of the stage, etc. I'll have to do it by eye. Not ideal :\ so a better solution is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could embed a .swf

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Demo extends Sprite{

    [Embed (source="test.swf")]
    private var Test : Class

    public function Demo() {

        var test : MovieClip = new Test() as MovieClip;
        addChild(test);

    }
}
}
```